# Typecasting hex as char without changing the value in C

Tags: c, casting, char, uint8t

```
void set_binuid(uint8_t byte, uint8_t i) {
    binuid[(i*4)]   = (byte >> 3) & 0x01;
    binuid[(i*4)+1] = (byte >> 2) & 0x01;
    binuid[(i*4)+2] = (byte >> 1) & 0x01;
    binuid[(i*4)+3] = (byte >> 0) & 0x01;
}
    
    
void hex_to_bin(void) {
    uint8_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (wieganduid[i] >= '0' && wieganduid[i] <= '9') {
            /* Numerical representation */
            set_binuid(wieganduid[i] - '0', i);
        } else {
            /* Number represented by a letter */
            switch(wieganduid[i]) { 
                    case 'A':
                            set_binuid(0x0A, i);
                            break; 
                    case 'B': 
                            set_binuid(0x0B, i);
                            break; 
                    case 'C': 
                            set_binuid(0x0C, i);
                            break; 
                    case 'D': 
                            set_binuid(0x0D, i);
                            break; 
                    case 'E': 
                            set_binuid(0x0E, i);
                            break; 
                    case 'F': 
                            set_binuid(0x0F, i);
                            break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am passing the value in these to functions to make binary array out of them, it workes fine as long as `uint8_t` contained only one hex number or it still works when the value taken in ascii table matches `1-f`, but when I get values like already mentioned EF - which converts to ascii `i` there is obviously no case for `i`, so Im need to take the EF and move it in another `uint8_t` with different hex value that would be `EF` in ascii for the function to work and give me bytes of binary `4` for `E` and `4` for `F`.

Comment: `i` is not `EF`, it is `69` in hex

Comment: Casting is like lying to the compiler. For example you can tell the compiler to pretend that your `uint8_t` value is really a value of type `short`. What it can't do is to convert a value to a string. For that use one of the [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) functions, like e.g. `snprintf`.

Comment: Also, hexadeximal, decimal, character, octal, those a just different ways of *presenting* the same binary value. For example `'A'`, `65`, `0101`, `0x41` are all the same value, all that differs is the presentation of the value.

Comment: Yeah, and I need to take one's value and use it as same "looks" of different value. EF stored as char or uint8 outputs 'i', I want to somehow copy it into another char that would output 'EF' but obviously would have different hex value.

Comment: `EF` is *two* characters. You can't store it in a single char or byte. You need at least two (and at least three if you want to treat it as a string).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the *real* problem you're trying to solve. *Why* do you need to store `EF` in another variable? What is that second variable supposed to be used for?

Comment: I've edited the question and tried to explain it as clearly as I can think of, please tell me if there's anything unclear

Comment: That check for a decimal digit could have been simplified by using [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit). There's also the problem of not checking for invalid "digits", or lower-case letters. Not to mention that one should never post images of text, least of all code (see https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: This is the first time I am using stackoverflow so bear with me :D, also im not checking for invalid/lowercase cause I know I wont get those in these variable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude dang, ty for posting the idownvotedbecause url. I knew it existed and used to use it but forgot its name

Comment: problem is , its not clear what you are trying to do. I mean hex_to_bin takes no args , so what 'hex' are you starting with and what is the 'bin' version supposed to contain. Is your input a string? like "42fc99bc" and you want an int out of it?

Comment: input is 1 byte, up to FF it takes the input narrows it down to binary 8 bits and stores them in 8 bytes ( 4 bytes for each symbol ).

Comment: @Broman3100 `0xEF` is outside the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) range because it has the high bit set. It is *not* the same as character `'i' == 0x69`. There exist 8-bit encodings which map `0xEF` to an extended character, for example `'ï' == 0xEF` in codepage [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) but that's not an `i`, even though your console/terminal may display it as an `i`, depending on the locale and font you are using.

Comment: That's correct but I dont need the ' ï ' in any way I need to copy the 'EF'.

Comment: Since I was unable to better explain my question and noone answering me I changed my plans of action and with it the question